# Why can't i use loops to take input of a char array?

Tags: c++, string, cin, chararray

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int size; char str[size]; cin>>size;
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cin>>str[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

example: size=10;
I was expecting this program to take 10 inputs but it is taking severral inputs.
if it has something to do with cin then please explain.

Comment: VLAs are not part of the C++ standard and for this reason alone you shouldn't be using them. However even if VLAs are available, you're creating the array before `size` is initialized, so the program has undefined behaviour...

Comment: Whatever resource you're using to learn C++, it seems to teach you more C than C++. Please invest in [some good C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), learn about the standard C++ string class `std::string`.

Comment: Apart from anything else if you want to create an array based on a size input by the user, then you have to create the array **after** you get the size from the user, not before.

Comment: Find the introduction to arrays (and variables, and the order in which code is executed) in a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list/388282#388282).

Comment: Why do you `#include <string>` and not use it?

Comment: how there is 2 upvote? is there any language that use size before get it would make sense?

Comment: *"example: size=10;"* -- don't say it; do it. Initialize `int size = 10;` and drop `cin>>size;`. Either this will make your problem easier to reproduce (no need to enter a size), or it will reveal a problem before the loop.

Comment: Also see [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Try it.

> ```
> #include<iostream>
> #include<string>
> using namespace std;
> int main()
> {
>     int size; 
>   cin>>size;
>   char str[size]; 
>     for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
>     {
>         cin>>str[i];
>     }
>     return 0;
> }
> ```

Comment: the size itself is definitely fine, the problem is only the array

Comment: "it doesn't get any answer" would not happens anyway.

Comment: i looked again and figure out.

Comment: this is not c++

Comment: well, this still use VLA, which is not standard c++.

Comment: *"I fixed it."* -- congratulations? Unfortunately, this site is not a competition to see who can "fix" it. It's purpose is providing (questions and) answers that explain something to readers. Code-only answers fail to explain almost every time. Better answers state the answer before posting any code.

Comment: @JaMiT When I figured out I just excited. So, I said "I fixed it". The answer is simple "cin>>size;" should come before the "char str[size]; "

Comment: hey you just inputted the size before creating the char array and the code worked fine could you please tell why declaration is affecting the program?

Answer (score -2):

It hasn't anything to do with the cin, to put 10 inputs you need to change the line 7 to "`for (int i=0; i<<size; i++)`" I haven't tried it yet but maybe it would solve your problem

Comment: it definitely wouldn't

Comment: `i<<size` means "left shift the value of `i` `size` bits", aka `i` * (2^`size`). It is not the solution to this problem.